# Fix PHP MySQL injection for login

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that signs a user into my site when they enter the correct login credentials. However, I noticed that it is easy to inject this login by entering `anything' OR 'x'='x` into the password box.

How can I stop this from happening?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sm_editors WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND password = '".$_POST['password']."' AND user_type != 'reader-for-approval'";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: How are we supposed to know which part is confusing you? Ask specific questions.

Comment: Never ever store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sm_editors WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' AND user_type != 'reader-for-approval'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to sanitize the inputs to prevent this.

The function `mysql_real_escape_string` will remove any escape characters.

Take a look at [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string function on data you pass to your query or use prepared statements and stored procedures instead of old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

first you can use mysql_real_escape_string to escape the string.

But a better way would be, when you would prepare your SQL string before you execute it. Have a look at PHP PDO MySQL connector. There you have some methods to prepare your string.

```
$s = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = :value');
$s->execute(array(':value' => $value));
```

hava a look at http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php